# HERE-sdk greatly increases the size of my application up to 150 mb. Google play has a limit on the apk up to 100 MB . How to solve

Tags: android, heremaps-android-sdk

To use here map in android, it requires to download the HERE-sdk.aar and HERE-sdk-javadoc.
Overall size of this files is 100 mb.
These files increases the size of my application up to 150 mb, because without these files size of my apk is 50 mb.

Google Play limits the size of the apk to 100 MB.

Can you advice please how do you solve this problem for your apk while working with here map?
How can I decrease size of this library or apk to match the limits of google play?

Comment: what is the apk analyzer is saying? and did you use shrinkResources true in grade

Comment: @UsamaAltaf Here is apk analyzer print screen https://prnt.sc/16quy7a "lib" - it is here map library. No I don't use "shrinkResources true". Will it help to reduce the size of the library? Thank you

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't help so much https://prnt.sc/16r2fl6